# Why does a custom document not show up in the bulk edit mode?

Tags: shopware6

I added a custom document as describied in the documentation. Which worked fine, and I can generate it on a single order.

When I go to the bulk edit mode, the standard documents are there, but not my custom document.
Do I have to do something else besides creating my doucument and type for it?

Answer (score 1):

As of today the document types available in the bulk edit form seem to be hardcoded. You will have to override the component to add your custom document type:

```js
Component.override('sw-bulk-edit-order', {
    computed: {
        documentsFormFields() {
            const formFields = this.$super('documentsFormFields');
 
            formFields.push({
                name: 'your_document_technical_name',
                labelHelpText: this.$tc('path.to.help-text'),
                config: {
                    componentName: 'plugin-bulk-edit-order-documents-generate-custom-document',
                    changeLabel: this.$tc('path.to.label'),
                },
            });

            return formFields;
        }
    },
});
```

You'll also need register a custom component like `plugin-bulk-edit-order-documents-generate-custom-document` to set the data for the document like a date or add a comment like for invoices. Have a look at the existing [`sw-bulk-edit-order-documents-generate-invoice`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/469a7fc7c7a60eea6ae0863f54cb489bc0cbf31c/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-bulk-edit/component/sw-bulk-edit-order/sw-bulk-edit-order-documents-generate-invoice/index.js) for reference.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I managed to get it going, but I had to edit 2 files in the shopware code, to add my document type. I couldnt extend the \administration\src\module\sw-bulk-edit\state\sw-bulk-edit.state.js, in which I had to add my document type for isChanged property... 
Is this going to be implmented soon? I there a task for it?

Comment: I forgot to tag you for the question above